Unhandled error starting Jupyterhub server
I try to deploy Jupyterhub use docker-compose and got an error when trying to start Jupyterhub Server:
2024-05-27 14:15:32 [E 2024-05-27 11:15:32.419 JupyterHub user:1002] Unhandled error 
starting aisachenko's server: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection 
aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

User aisachenko has got access to var/run/docker.sock
aisachenko@MacBook-Pro-Admin-2 jupyterhub-deploy % ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon  41 27 май 13:00 /var/run/docker.sock -> 
/Users/aisachenko/.docker/run/docker.sock

My Spawner settings:
c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'dockerspawner.DockerSpawner'
c.DockerSpawner.image = 'jupyter/base-notebook:latest'
c.DockerSpawner.use_internal_ip = True
c.DockerSpawner.network_name = 'jupyterhub_network'
c.DockerSpawner.extra_host_config = {'network_mode': 'jupyterhub_network'}
c.DockerSpawner.remove = True
c.DockerSpawner.debug = True
c.DockerSpawner.client_kwargs = {'base_url': 'unix://var/run/docker.sock', 'version': 
'auto'}

Please, help me
